# CI_session and Error Number: 1054 (Unknown column ...)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have got problem with ci_session. When I am creating query with Active Record and I use session, it throws me Error Number: 1054.
It is caused by Session.php . I am using database session and when it executes sess_write(), then it throws error.

Can I create new instance of $this->db ? 
Error is at line no. 289 in Session.php

```
$this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));
```

In this place is set $this->CI->db->order_by(‘something’), from my code, before I call $this->session and this is my problem.

EDIT (13:12):

```
Unknown column 'contract.created' in 'order clause'

UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1393330303, `user_data` = 'some_data' WHERE `session_id` = 'ea330d7194f902b6b38b88d509766560' ORDER BY `contract`.`created` DESC LIMIT 30

Filename: C:\Apache24\htdocs\Trokadero_v5\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

EDIT 2:

I am sure, it is happening by Active Record , because sequence of AR tasks is:

My_controller.php

```
$this->db->order_by('contract.created', 'DESC');
$this->session->set_flashdata('order_by_direction', 'DESC');
```

And then is executing in Session.php, with my own order_by clause

```
$this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));
```

Comment: check your table column names and post your full error message in question.

Comment: remove order by line in code as it is not required for update query.

Comment: comment out order_by line in your controller.

Comment: I can not. In my solution it is necessary to use db_session inside buildgin my query.. Ah.. I must rewrite my code, I think..

Comment: Add you full code. Then only i can give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
$this->session->userdata();
$this->session->set_userdata();
etc.
```

MUST BE used before/after execute your own CRUD ($this->db->...).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you have to reset the db query.

```
$this->db->order_by('contract.created', 'DESC');
// add line of code to get data. After getting data, reset the db object.
$this->db->_reset_write();
$this->session->set_flashdata('order_by_direction', 'DESC');
```