# CI_SESSION unknown table in 'order clause'

Tags: codeigniter, session

I use database table to store the ci_session. Here is my controller:

```
public function displayAllArticles() 
    {
        // custom limit, set in zconfig for all tables
        $customLimit = $this->config->item('articles_per_page');
        // get the total number or records
        $totalARTresults = $this->db->get('article')->num_rows();
        // set the paging variables
        if ($this->uri->segment(4) !="") 
        { 
            $limit = $this->uri->segment(4); 
        } else { 
            $limit = $customLimit; 
        } 
        $offset = 5; 
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(5); 
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        // line bellow is the offending line <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $this->db->order_by('articlecategoryID desc, articleSorder asc'); 
        $data['articles'] = $this->articlesModel->get_with_category();
        // session variables bellow are used in the view, for the 
        // code that display the message: Displaying x to y from total of z records

        $this->session->set_userdata('totalARTresults', $totalARTresults);
        $this->session->set_userdata('limit', $limit);
        $this->session->set_userdata('offset', $offset);  
        $data['articles'] = array_splice($data['articles'], $offset, $limit);
        // paging configuration
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backEnd/articles/displayAllArticles/'.$limit.'/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalARTresults;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a href=# style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#258BB5;">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        // initialize the paging
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
        // create & load the variables needed for the view 
        $errorMessage = '';
        $data['main_content'] = 'articles/articles';
        $data['title'] = 'Articles';
        $this->load->vars($data,$errorMessage);
        $this->load->vars($this->currentUser);
        $this->load->view('backOffice/template');  
    }   // end of function displayAllArticles
```

When i call this function, i  get the error message:

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'article.articlecategoryID' in 'order clause'
UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1398256604, `...........

I have searched this site, and I found this:
[CI_session and Error Number: 1054 (Unknown column ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013747/ci-session-and-error-number-1054-unknown-column)
but the solution: $this->db->_reset_write();
doesn't work.

Author there says that:
$this->session->userdata();
$this->session->set_userdata();
etc...
MUST BE used before/after execute your own CRUD ($this->db->...), but where ever i move the code for the session, i get same error.

Anyone can give me a hand with this? I know that I can just remove the order_by clausule in my controller, but I have plenty of legacy code that will have to be changed if I do so.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following things -

**1) Order of auto-loading libraries (config/autoload.php)**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','upload','session','form_validation');
// session loaded after database library
```

**2) Having a `ci_sessions` table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
   session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
   last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   user_data text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
   KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);

//Refer: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
// ensure table name: ci_sessions
```

**3) Enable use of `ci_sessions` table in `config/config.php`**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';    // ensure table name: ci_sessions
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] =  86400 * 30; //30 days
```

Comment: all above has been done, that is:$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session'); $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; and the table is already in place. Any other sugesstion?